# Boot script execution order (rc.local)?

Tags: networking, startup, boot, xen, rc

With some great help from another user on here I've managed to create a script which writes the necessary network configurations required to `/etc/network/interfaces` and allow public access to a DomU server.

I’ve placed this script in the `/etc/rc.local` file, and executed `chmod u+x /etc/rc.local` to enable it.

The server is a DomU Ubuntu server on the a host (Dom0). And `rc.local` doesn't seem to be executing before the network is brought up at boot/creation time.

So the configuration changes are being made to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, but are not active once the boot process completes. I have to reboot once more before the changes take effect.

I've tried adding `/etc/init.d/networking restart` to the the end of the `rc.local` script (before `exit 0`), but with no joy.

I also tried adding the script to the `S35networking` file, but again without success.

Any advice or suggestions on getting this script to execute before the network device is brought up would be greatly appreciated.?

Comment: So why don't you restart network service from your script itself ?
I mean once configuration is changed, restart the network service and new configuration will be in effect.

Comment: Hi. Yep. Tried that. I added `/etc/init.d/networking restart` to the script but it doesn't seem to work. :(

Comment: can you confirm this?
"and executed chmod u+x /etc/rc.local to enable it."
rc.local has already required perms. you nedd to make your script executable.

Comment: Yes. I may not have been 100% clear. The script works once a second reboot takes place. But not on the very first boot once the DomU server is created. Hope that makes more sense?